# Proving $||u||_b \leq ||u||_a^\lambda||u||_c^{1-\lambda}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

Here is an interpolation inequality of the norms: if $a\leq b\leq c$ and suppose $\lambda$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{b}=\frac{\lambda}{a}+\frac{1-\lambda}{c}$$

then $$||u||_b \leq ||u||_a^\lambda||u||_c^{1-\lambda}$$

I tried taking logarithm of both sides and tried to apply Holder without success. How might we prove this?

Comment: Young's inequality could be useful - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: I imagine you should just mimic the proof of Holder's inequality